# Spring MVC portlet not deploying

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I wrote a simple spring mvc portlet and I copied to "deploy" in liferay it is not automatically getting deployed to tomcat's webapp folder.

Further it is deploying only when the tomcat is restarted.

Also the portal having the spring mvc portlet is not automatically refreshed with the new content.
I had to remove it and add it again.
I tried with a simple portlet app and everything happens automatically by default.

Can you tell me what I am missing here in spring mvc portlet app.

Any suggestions would be helpful..

Comment: Do you get any errors on deployment, if so can you add your stacktrace?

Comment: No i don't get any errors while deployment. I checked in catalina.out file in tomcat logs folder.

Comment: Basically my hot deployment feature is not working. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Without looking at the your configuration it's tricky, especially as some portlets are deploying and others aren't. Did you create this portlet from scratch?

Comment: What do you use to `copy` the portlet?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us the log from the moment you copied the portlet to the auto deploy folder. I believe it is getting blacklisted because of some reason and thats why on restart it auto deploys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/88234) from liferay forum might help you.

Just check if the property `auto.deploy.interval=0` or `auto.deploy.enabled=false` is not set.